# Keeping url when redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two websites:

- www.parkeddomain.com
- www.realdomain.com

All requests from www.parkeddomain.com get redirected to www.realdomain. There's no server associated with www.parkeddomain.com. So I can't make an .htaccess file there.

I want all requests to get forwarded, so www.parkeddomain.com/url becomes www.realdomain.com/url. I've tried using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^parkeddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.realdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it's not working. Most I've gotten is an infinite redirect.

Is it possible to do this using the .htaccess on www.realdomain.com and how should it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a check on host header not referrer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}      ^(www\.)?parkeddomain\.com$
RewriteRule  (.*)   http://www.realdomain.com/$1
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it isn't working. I've contacted my hoster to see what they can do.

Comment: **unfortunately it isn't working**.  It isn't really technical explanation of what is happening. Can you explain what happens? connection error? 403? 404? 5xx?

Comment: Nothing is happening, so I have no technical explanation. It just displays the same behavior as without the rule.

Comment: Clear your cache. Your previous rule had `301`  HTTP response code which is permanent redirect, so browsers cache the result.